# Tomcat caters to multiple user with same memory - JSP

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, session-state

I have a jsp web application, When i try to deploy it to tomcat server, and try to run the application from different machines, i dont get new pages for every user.

My application takes input from html input and keep it in the memory with the press of the button, ao actually i push the values in the memory and keeps it untill reset is pressed.
The problem comes when i goto another machine and run that application, all i get is the same modified page from that previous user.

I have used session management to keep username in the session.
But as if my application is not creating a new session for every new user request.

eg:

> main.jsp has some input fields and when i click 'add' those values from html input is stored in memory objects, and is showed in the html inputs till the memory is not cleared.
>
> Now from another machine, i access this application and go to main.jsp, there i get prefilled html input boxes.

why am i not getting a new page everytime i go from a different machine.
Is tomcat server serves all users from same memory space?

Sample code for main.jsp

```
 <%@ page import="test.DatabaseAccessConnectionManager" %>
<%@ page import="test.FunctionKeywordManager" %>
<%@ page import="test.TestScenarioManager" %>
<%@ page import="test.DataParameter" %>
<%@ page import="test.RepositoryManager" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ListIterator"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>  
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>  
<%@ page import="test.TestCase" %>
<%@ page import="test.ReportGenerator" %>
<jsp:useBean id="connn" scope="session" class="test.DatabaseAccessConnectionManager"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="connn1" scope="session" class="test.FunctionKeywordManager"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="connn2" scope="session" class="test.TestScenarioManager"></jsp:useBean>
<% 
String Username=null;
String projectName = null;
if(session.getAttribute("Username")!=null)
{
    Username = session.getAttribute("Username").toString();
    projectName = session.getAttribute("ProjectName").toString();
}
else
{
response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp"); 
}
%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test Scenario Management</title>
<script src="static/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/style.css">
<!-- <script>
function displayMessage(strMessage) {
        alert(strMessage);
};
</script> -->
</head>
<body>

<div id="parameterPopup">
<div class="heading">Enter Parameter Values</div>
<br>
<div class="content"></div>
<br>
<div class="buttons">
<input type="button" value="submit values" id="btnSubmitParams" />
</div>
</div>


<div id="wrapper">
<div id="userInfonLogout">
   <p>Welcome <b><%=Username %></b></p>
<center><a href="Logout.jsp" >logout</a></center>
</div>
<div id="topheader">
<div id="logo">
<img src="static/images/CS_200px.png"/>
</div>
<center><div id="headertext"><h1>Data Validation Automation</h1></div>                 </center>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="Dashboard.jsp">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Projects.jsp">Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="Repository.jsp">Repository</a></li>
<li><a href="CreateTestScenario.jsp">Create Test Scenario</a></li>
<li><a href="ExistingTestScenarioManagement.jsp">Maintain Test     Scenarios</a></li>
<li><a href="Config.jsp">Configuration</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
 <div id="body">
 <div id="popup" style="display:none">

 <div class="content">
 </div>
 <input type="button" class="close" value="close"/>
</div>
<h2>
<p align="center">
Create Test Scenario</p></h2>
<%!
FunctionKeywordManager objFunctionKeywordManager;
List<String> listKeywords;
TestScenarioManager objTestScenarioManager;
ReportGenerator objReportGenerator=new ReportGenerator();
public void jspInit(){
objFunctionKeywordManager = new FunctionKeywordManager();
listKeywords = objFunctionKeywordManager.getAllFunctionKeyword();
objTestScenarioManager = new TestScenarioManager();
}  
%>
<%
RepositoryManager objRM = new RepositoryManager();
List<String> listRepo = objRM.getRepositoryListForProject(projectName);
%>
```

P.S: A newbie to jsp and tomcat.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your servlet code? I suspect that your code is not written for the multi-threading environment in tomcat.

Comment: It's confidential? This code is paid for?!

Comment: Oh I get it, it's April Fool's Day :D I admit it, you *totally* got me! Well-played, sir.

Comment: Read: http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/WhyNotUseScriptlets.

Comment: A jsp will be compiled into a servlet so String Username=null;
String projectName = null; will be treated as member variables and will not be thread safe. http://books.msspace.net/mirrorbooks/javaserverpages24hours/0672325977_ch01lev1sec6.html

Comment: @Jaydee There's a difference between `<%!` and `<%`. Note in the link you provide one solution is to use a variable inside `<%`.

Comment: @DaveNewton Heh. Fair point